# How to create a weekly job that transfers all leads with Lead Status field = “Junk (c)” and moves them all to the Dead Queue

Tags: queue, jobs

How to create a weekly job that transfers all leads with Lead Status field = “Junk (c)” and moves them all to the Dead Queue (dead queue is a queue created).

Can I add filter on mass transfer or should I create a workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a weekly job, consider the following

1. Create a time-based workflow on Lead where the entry criteria is `status = Junk(c)` and owner is not the junk queue
2. Have a time-based action that fires at +7 days from trigger date and does a field update on `Lead.owner` to queue `Junk`.

If the Lead comes out of Junk status before the week has passed, the time-based action is removed automatically by SFDC.

The advantage of the above is you don't have to worry about writing any APEX, or running a job on a platform other than SFDC.

The only consideration here is what to do about existing records in Junk status as they won;t have the time-based workflow actions already applied. Here, you'll need to mass edit them using Data Loader (or equivalent tool) or Execute Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

For a weekly job your best shot would be to use the Command Line Interface (CLI) of dataloader (upsert) in combination with the scheduler of your OS (e.g. Windows scheduler). Dataloader can be invoked using the scheduler of your system OS to call a batch file that will in turn call the Data Loader.

To use the Dataloader CLI, you find details [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line).

Comment: hmm -- I would do this with time-based workflow, am I missing something?

Comment: @crop1645 I see how you can use a single time triggered event using wf. But how do you schedule a repeating (weekly) event with time triggered wf?

Comment: But why does it have to be repeating? once the Junk lead is moved into the queue, you don't need to look at it again unless it comes out of the queue becomes non junk, then goes to junk again.

Comment: You are probably right :-)  but he's asking for a weekly job